# SSL TIdHTTP with Socks

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I'm using `TIdHTTP` a lot in my applications and users of mine requested a Socks4/5 feature with a specific timeout. I use my application to communicate with a SSL Website and I only worked with the regular `ProxyParams` before. 
How can I add Socks4 and/or Socks5 support to my `TIdHTTP` Component with a specific timeout?

Edit:

Since I don't have any Socks4/Socks5 proxies, I created my own with a new application to test.
I added `TIdSocksServer` and assigned a `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` to it.
To make sure it connections I added a Messagebox to the `OnConnect`. The server listens on Port 8080 and is set to `Active:=True;`

Here is my code to with my `TIdHTTP` Component:

```
procedure NewQuery;
var
 IDHTTP                                : TIdHTTP;
 SSL                                   : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
 Socks                                 : TIdSocksInfo;
begin
 Socks                                 := TidSocksInfo.Create (NIL);
 IDHTTP                                := TIdHTTP.Create(NIL);
 SSL                                   := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(NIL);
 IDHTTP.IOHandler                      := SSL;
 SSL.TransparentProxy                  := Socks;
 Socks.Host                            := 'localhost';
 Socks.Port                            := 8080;
 Socks.Authentication                  := saNoAuthentication;
 Socks.Version                         := svSocks4; // or svSocks5
 IDHTTP.ConnectTimeout                 := 5000; // 5 seconds
 IDHTTP.Get ('www.google.com');
end;
```

Not sure if I used this the right way but it seems like that the GET request works without having it connected to the socks server. Am I using it wrong?

Comment: When a TransparentProxy component does not have an `Owner` assigned, the `IOHandler.TransparentProxy` property setter has special logic to make a new owned copy of the TransparentProxy rather than use the original you passed in. So watch out for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a `TIdSocksInfo` component to the IOHandler's `TransparentProxy` property.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the `TransparentProxy` property.

Comment: I've edited my question and it seems like that I missed something. I'm sorry to bother you (again), but would you mind taking a look again and provide a more detailed answer please?

Comment: Don't add SSL to your SOCKS server. A client would establish a connection to the proxy first, have the proxy establish a connection to the target server, and then the client would negotiate an SSL session directly with the target server, not with the proxy.

Comment: I understand. So my code is right? It seems like it doesn't do anything at all cause even if I set the socks host and port to a non listening address it still establishes a connection to the webserver like there was no socks info at all.

Comment: Change the code to give the `TIdSocksInfo` a non-nil `Owner`. Otherwise the `IOHandler` will make an internal copy of the `TIdSocksInfo` but the Host/Port does not get carried over to the copy.  I would suggest making the `TIdHTTP` be the `Owner` of both the `IOHandler` and the `TIdSocksInfo`.